# Paypal IPN and transaction IDs

Tags: paypal

I currently have a simple Paypal button on my website where people enter some information which is saved into a database, and the button then takes them to paypal to pay £20 to join.  The problem is there is no link between the website and paypal, so I have to manually cross check who has joined on the website against Paypal each time.

I've looked into Paypal IPN which looks ideal, but I can't work out how to match the transactions up.

i.e. IPN sends me a txn_id, but I don't have that at my end.  I need a way to send a generate & save a unique ID per transaction, that goes to Paypal with the user, and Paypal then sends back to me via IPN.

I'm quite lost in Paypals shoddy docs, so any help from SO would help!

(Off topic rant: why to Paypal have so many domains: paypal.com, paypal-business.com, x.com, paypal-marketing.com,...  Can they not spell phishing?!)

Comment: You use the transaction id to pull additional information about the transaction itself.  Furthermore all you need is the paypal account username and the transaction id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass YOUR id (like the DB row id) to Paypal with `custom` variable, you can cross reference it using the `custom` variable from IPN.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables

Comment: So can I add in my HTML for the button something like: `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="some_unique_code">` and that gets passed back to my via IPN?

Comment: I voted this back up.  The answer makes perfect sense.  There is another field, though, called INVOICE you could use in place of CUSTOM if you're working with an actual order/invoice ID of some sort.  Both would work the same, but I like to save CUSTOM for things that don't have specific fields already.  Either way, you could use the returned field to relate back to your existing DB tables if you're saving all IPN data separately, or just update the existing record using the INVOICE/CUSTOM value as a key.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't know who down voted it!  I'll check this works and then mark the answer as correct if/when it does.  It sounds ideal

Comment: This works fine.  Add `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="marks unique id!">` to your HTML for the button, and it comes back in $_POST['custom'] from the IPN post.  Many Thanks!